# AngularJS 2.0 official?

Tags: angular

All:

Just search the progress of AngularJS 2.0 release,  and it leads me to https://angular.io/

I wonder if this is Google Official site for AngularJS 2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.. that is the official site..API methods are changing rapidly https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes its the [Official Google Site](https://angular.io/)** (the old one is [https://angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/)).

You can see whether Angular 2.0 is ready or not [here](https://splintercode.github.io/is-angular-2-ready/).

Note there are currently 74 issues to fix before releasing Angular 2.0 beta.

Comment: Thanks, one beginner question about the study direction, should I start to focus on React.js or AngularJS 2.0? Both seems promising, but I kinda wondering which could gain more community and popularity? BTW, my direction is more like mobile app and small web app

Comment: @Maarten Yes, I wrote NG 1.0 before. But one thing I am a little worried is the typescript( it says that A2.0 is built with typescript), anything related to microsoft make me worried( from windows to visualstudio to its phone), I kinda wondering the future of typescript will affect A2.0 heavily

Comment: They are both top-level javascript frameworks that are currently avaiable, with a huge web company behind them (Facebook developed and using react.js, and Google created angular.js). they are both promising. personally I am working heavily with angular 1.4 and not moving to angular 2.0 yet because its unstable, api changes frequently, have a tiny community and not production ready. I haven't learned React.js yet, but its great as well. Personally, I would advice you learning first angular 1.4 to get familier with a complex javascript framework, it will help you either way you will choose later

Comment: @Aviran Yes, I wrote NG 1.0 before. But one thing I am a little worried is the typescript( it says that A2.0 is built with typescript), anything related to microsoft make me worried( from windows to visualstudio to its phone), I kinda wondering the future of typescript will affect A2.0 heavily

Comment: A2 is not requiring Typescript

Comment: Note that react.js came out at 2013, while angular initially released at 2009. The Angular's echosystem is much greater, it will take time until react.js will become as popular as angular.

Comment: @Kuan You shouldn't be worried about Typescript. Since nowadays javascript is being used on large and complex applications, the native javascript language has many issues - large amount of code becomes messy, no type safety, unclear syntax etc. Typescript fix these issues by making a friendlier language that "compiles" into javascript (which is still readable by human, as opposed to CoffeeScript). Its gaining more and more popularity over all the other alternatives. Eventhough I understand your concerns over Microsoft, I promise you they did great this time :)

Comment: @Aviran Thanks, this make me eased.

Comment: @Aviran Thanks for the confidence. I came across this post which seems a Nahh to A2.0, could you read and give some of your opinion about this post? http://blog.founddrama.net/2015/10/9-thoughts-about-4-hours-with-angularjs-2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the official one, which is on a different domain because they kept the angularjs.org one for 1.*.

Comment: Thanks, one beginner question about the study direction, should I start to focus on React.js or AngularJS 2.0? Both seems promising, but I kinda wondering which could gain more community and popularity? BTW, my direction is more like mobile app and small web app

Comment: hard one. React.js is here already, A2 is nearly there. Both are good on mobile, Angular has a bigger reach and is using the better ideas from reactjs, so my preference is there

Comment: So from your point, if have not started React, then probably it is the good time to read A2.0?

Comment: @Kuan if you are already familier with Angular 1.4 and you want to take the next step in that direction to the near future technology I would recommend you start learning ES6 with Angular 2.0, but learning React.js to extand your programing perspectives can be beneficial as well.